# Symfony2 choice constraint/validation on entity field type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity field type with multiple selection :

```
$builder
  ->add('products', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Product',
    'choices' => $this->getAvailableProducts(),
    'multiple' => true,
  ))
;
```

I would like to add a min/max constraint on this field,

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Choice;
...
'constraints' => array(new Choice(array(
    'min' => $min,
    'max' => $max,
    'multiple' => true,
    'choices' => $this->getAvailableProducts()->toArray(),
))),
```

But in this case, when the form is bound, the value bound for the 'products' field is a doctrine ArrayCollection, the validator throw an exception if an array is not given. "Expected argument of type array, object given"

Does it mean I have to use a 'choice' field in order to use the min/max constraint ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have multiple set to true the validator will receive a collection after binding your form.

You can validate the number of entites in the collection using the [**count**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html) validation constraint.

### The Count validation constraint

> Validates that a given collection's (i.e. an array or an object that
>   implements Countable) element count is between some minimum and
>   maximum value.

Comment: Ok ! But how can i add min/max constraint to my collection validation ?

Comment: Ah sorry i think i misunderstood your question. You want to validate the number of selected entities  right?

Comment: Yep ! I just want to be able to specify a min/max number of entities selectable

Comment: Then you need the Count validation constraint ;) updated my answer.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? (it should actually) If yes please upvote/accept otherwise leave a comment so we can track this down further.

Comment: Yes it did ! Sorry just took some time before implementing it. Thx